# Switching theme by button Codename One

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm having issues when I change my theme, I have a default theme and a theme called Blue, I change to Blue by pressing a button then it's working good untill I get back to my main Menu then it changes back to my default theme by overriding my Blue theme. I want to avoid it.

This is my initVars:

```
protected void initVars(Resources res){
    Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu(false);
}
```

This is my button to do the change:

```
@Override
protected void onMain_Button4Action(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
     UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "Blue");
     Display.getInstance().getCurrent().refreshTheme();
}
```

And this is my button function to back to my main Menu:

```
back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) 
            {
                new StateMachine("/theme");
            }
        });
```

Should I set something in initVars or in my ActionListener to avoid overriding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest staring over with a new project. You are using the old GUI builder which is deprecated.

Assuming both themes are in the main res file you don't need to do that. You just need a reference to the resource file which you can get in the old GUI builder using `fetchResourceFile()`.

```
Hashtable themeData = theme.getTheme("Theme Name");
UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(themeData);
Display.getInstance().getCurrent().refreshTheme();
```

Comment: I can only open the new GuiBuilder by right clicking on my GuiForm.java then selecting Gui Builder option the one with the Codename One Icon instead of going to Open With > GuiBuilder which is not working. Also the Mapper theme I'm only able to set it by the wizard when creating a new project, after that if I decide to set a Mapper theme by editing the theme.res so the Mapper theme loads like a blank theme instead. It only happens with the Mapper theme.

Comment: I'm using the new Gui Builder now, I created a Label and I clicked on [Pick Image], a menu comes up `"Choose from where to pick an image"` then I select `"from res File"`, but I can't find my image there. Where should I add my customized images, to my src/res/theme directory? Is there any size/resolution restrictions?

Comment: Did you save the resource file after adding the image? Did you close and reopen the gui builder?

Comment: Thanks, it's working good, I didn't know that the right way to add images into the resource file is by editing the theme.res, I was placing the files straight to the folder directory instead. What about the Mapper theme, how to fix that bug?

Comment: Whenever I add an action event for a Button using the new Gui Builder I got this error:
`Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'My Project'.
Ant build D:\Documents\Rafa\eclipse-workspace\My Project\build.xml already in progress. Concurrent Ant builds are possible if you specify to build in a separate JRE.
Ant build D:\Documents\Rafa\eclipse-workspace\My Project\build.xml already in progress. Concurrent Ant builds are possible if you specify to build in a separate JRE.` It still working but should I worry about it?

Comment: It's one of those annoying cases with eclipses incremental compiler getting ahead of itself. It's hard to fix these cases on our side.